# How to add multiple ssh keys to Publish Over SSH Plugin in jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-cli

I am using jenkins to build and publish my project.
I am using the Publish Over SSH plugin to push my artifacts to the server.
I was able to configure only one ssh key for the plugin in the Jenkins setting . Is it possible to add multiple keys and multiple hosts to that plugin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can add multiple keys and hosts to the plugin. After you install the plugin, open any job and go to configuration. Here you can add multiple servers (Hosts) and keys for each of the server.

Comment: Can you please explain the steps to do the same?

Comment: Steps: Add a new server and provide name, hostname, username. Then click on Advanced. Paste the private key in the box with label key.

Answer (score 3):

To add multiple keys for different hosts, Just add host and tick advanced options. You will see 'Use password authentication or use a different key', tick this box and enter your new key. 
Hope this helps!